# exsheets: How to print solutions to a very specific section?

Tags: exsheets

I write some questions and answers with the `exsheets` package. I want to print the solution of a specific section, e.g. the solutions from section 2 of chapter 2.

**What doesn't work**

- `\printsolutions[section={2}]`: this command prints the solutions of every section 2 in the document (e.g. section 2 of chapter 1 and section 2 of chapter 2)
- to label the section with `\exlabel{sec:mysection}` and print the solutions with `\printsolutions[section={-\S{sec:mysection}}]` which will print all solutions from questions up to and including the labeled section

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within=section,
  counter-format=ch.se.qu[1]
}

\begin{document}
  \part{EXCERCISES}
    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

    \chapter{Topic 2}

      \section{Section}\exlabel{sec:sectionone}
        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}\exlabel{sec:sectiontwo}
        \begin{question}
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \part{SOLUTIONS}

    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[section={1}] % there should be only the solution to 1.1.1

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[section={2}] % there should be only the solution to 1.2.1

    \chapter{Topic 2}

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[section={-\S{sec:sectionone}}] % there should be only the solution to 2.1.1

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[section={-\S{sec:sectiontwo}}] % there should be only the solution to 2.2.1

\end{document}
```

**EDIT: There is a workaround**

To get the desired result you can use `[ID=1]` to give questions an ID and `\printsolutions[byID={1}]` to print the solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within=section,
  counter-format=ch.se.qu[1]
}

\begin{document}
  \part{EXCERCISES}
    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}[ID=111]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}

        \begin{question}[ID=121]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

    \chapter{Topic 2}

      \section{Section}
        \begin{question}[ID=211]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

      \section{Section}
        \begin{question}[ID=221]
        I'm an excercise.
        \end{question}
        \begin{solution}
        I'm an solution.
        \end{solution}

  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \part{SOLUTIONS}

    \chapter{Topic 1}

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={111}]

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={121}]

    \chapter{Topic 2}

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={211}]

      \section{Section}
        \printsolutions[byID={221}]

\end{document}
```

PS: I hope there'll be a feature soon, Clemens ;)

Comment: I asked the same question a year ago and got no answer/comment so the question got deleted in the meantime. At least now you got a comment :) I solved the issue by eliminating the need to do the printing per section but a quick solution I came up with before that was to continue section numbering across chapters. With that solution your MWE would look like this: http://pasted.co/5b29e5df

Comment: Just posted a [feature request on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/24/print-solutions-by-chapter-and-section).

Comment: I'll try to come up with something (maybe tomorrow) but I won't promise anything.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider BTW: I haven't forgotten: https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/34/

Comment: The news is this: `exsheets` itself is not going to be updated any more but I nearly finished its successor package [`xsim`](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim) which supports this: `\printsolutions[chapter=2,section=3]`